# Undefined Variable: repmat in Scilab

Tags: scilab

`repmat` is [supposed to be a builtin function](https://help.scilab.org/doc/6.0.0/en_US/repmat.html) in scilab, yet when I try to run my script using the batch launcher `scilab.bat -ns -f myfile.sce`, I get the error message

> `Undefined Variable: repmat`

This is a fresh install of Scilab 6.0.1 on Windows 10. I've run the command from cygwin and also tried to execute the script using the GUI that popped open.

`diag` for example is available. `flipdim`, which is also among the [matrix manipulations](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/section_02944b44829437417dd30a92d80d639a.html) is also not though.

Clicking `File > Open a file` in the GUI results in

> `Undefined variable: main_menubar_cb`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I executed my script in the GUI that opened after the command `scilab.bat -ns -f myfile.sce`. Closing that GUI and opening it through the windows search worked!

Running it with `scilab.bat -f myfile.sce` also worked.

It seems to be the `-ns` flag that is the issue.
`scilab.bat --help` states:

> ```
>   -nw              : Enable console mode.
>   -nwni            : Enable terminal mode.
>   -ns              : Don't execute etc/scilab.start.
>   --help           : Display this help.
> ```

Thus, that makes sense.

The flags I would have wanted to see the output in my terminal would have been `-nw -f` instead.

**Solution:**
Use `scilab.bat -nw -f myfile.sce` instead.